# Azure WAF support for OData

Tags: owasp, waf, azure

I have noticed some of the OWASP rules from Azure WAF are rejecting OData default filtered such as `$select`, suspecting it to be SQL injection. How can you handle the nature of OData from Azure WAF?

```
1. Warning. Pattern match \"(^[\"'`;]+|[\"'`]+$)\" at ARGS:$filter
2. Matched Data: $select found within ARGS_NAMES:$select: $select
```

Comment: Is there any other information about what rules have triggered? In Azure WAF, can you add any exclusion?

Comment: You are paying for the Azure OWASP Core Rule Set integration. What does the paid support say?